# Discord.py have a user choose between 2 reactions

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my discord bot have a higher or lower game where the player clicks an up or down arrow to guess, but I'm struggling to work out how check if the reaction is the first one or the second one.

Here is my code so far (its in a cog):

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def highlow(self, ctx, limit:int = 100, *args):
    num = random.randint(0, limit)

    msg = await ctx.reply("The number is {num} \nWHould you like to go (h)igher or (l)ower")

    await self.client.add_reaction(msg, emoji="<:arrow_up:>")
    await self.client.add_reaction(msg, emoji="<:arrow_down:>")

    def check(reaction, user):

      return reaction.message == msg and str(reaction.emoji) ==  '<:arrow_down:>'

    

    await self.client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
```

(Also, I am aware that `self.client.add_reaction` will not work, its some old code I just quickly copied over to test out)

How do I make it so that I can check either reaction instead of just one?

Comment: The `client.wait_for` will return the `reaction` object. You can check from there.

Comment: Also there's no such thing as `client.add_reaction`

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński i just edited my answer explaining

Comment: You can see the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) for `wait_for`

Answer (score 1):

To add a reaction we use `msg.add_reaction("Your reaction")` in your case.

If you want to check the reaction of a user we `wait_for` a `reaction_add`.

***You can have a look at the following code:***

```py
try:
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
    while user == client.user:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "YourEmoji": # First reaction
        # Do what you want to do
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "YourEmoji": # Second reaction
        # Do what you want to do
except Exception: # Timeout can be added for example
    return
```

Here we check that the bot reaction is not counting as a valid reaction but instead a user one. You can then add more `if`-statements in your code.